# Php error: "Filename cannot be empty"

Tags: php, validation

I'm creating a site that let's the user put in information and later save it to a document on the computer using PHP read/write. Everything is working fine except I'm getting two errors.

The errors are "Undefined offset: 6 in C:\wamp\www\Phoenix\ReadWrite.php on line 109" and " fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp\www\Phoenix\ReadWrite.php on line 110".
This is the code:

```
<?php
$nameErr = $ssnErr = $dateErr = $timeErr = $fileErr ="";
$name = $ssn = $date = $time = $comment = $file = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["1"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
     $_POST['6'] = "";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["1"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["2"])) {
     $ssnErr = "SSN is required";
     $_POST['6'] = "";
   } else {
     $ssn = test_input($_POST["2"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["3"])) {
     $dateErr = "Date is required";
     $_POST['6'] = "";
   } else {
     $date = test_input($_POST["3"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["4"])) {
     $timeErr = "Time is required";
     $_POST['6'] = "";
   } else {
     $time = test_input($_POST["4"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["5"])) {
     $comment = "";
   } else {
     $comment = test_input($_POST["5"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["6"])) {
     $fileErr = "Filename is required";
   } else {
     $file = test_input($_POST["6"]);
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td scope="col">Name:</td>
    <td colspan="2" scope="col"><input type="text" name="1"></td>
    <td><span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SSN:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="2"></td>
    <td><span class="error"><?php echo $ssnErr;?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="3"></td>
    <td><span class="error"><?php echo $dateErr;?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Time of Arrival:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="4"></td>
    <td><span class="error"><?php echo $timeErr;?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Comment:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><textarea rows="7" cols="30" name="5"></textarea></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Filename:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="6"></td>
    <td><span class="error"><?php echo $fileErr;?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> </td>
    <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" ></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
</form>

<?php
$file = $_POST['6'];
$myfile = fopen($file, "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$one = "\r\n" . $_POST['1'] . "\r\n";
fwrite($myfile, $one);
$two = $_POST['2'] . "\r\n";
fwrite($myfile, $two);
$three =$_POST['3'] . "\r\n";
fwrite($myfile, $three);
$four =$_POST['4'] . "\r\n";
fwrite($myfile, $four);
$five = $_POST['5'] . "\r\n";
fwrite($myfile, $five);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

My question is: how can i solve the problem with the empty field in my form?

Comment: I would not recommend using numbers for input names in your case. It makes it hard to figure out what's going on. Best just name them 'name', 'ssn', 'date', etc.

Comment: in your case $_POST['6'] is empty when form is submitted check if isset first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to work with `$_POST` before the form is sent.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['6'])) {
    $file = $_POST['6'];
    $myfile = fopen($file, "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $one = "\r\n" . $_POST['1'] . "\r\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $one);
    $two = $_POST['2'] . "\r\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $two);
    $three =$_POST['3'] . "\r\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $three);
    $four =$_POST['4'] . "\r\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $four);
    $five = $_POST['5'] . "\r\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $five);
    fclose($myfile);
}

?>
```

Better way is to create the whole content and then put that into file.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['6'])) {
    $file = $_POST['6'];
    $myfile = fopen($file, "a");

    $content = "\r\n" . $_POST['1'] . "\r\n" . 
                        $_POST['2'] . "\r\n" . 
                        $_POST['3'] . "\r\n" . 
                        $_POST['4'] . "\r\n" . 
                        $_POST['5'] . "\r\n";

    fwrite($myfile, $content);
    fclose($myfile);
}

?>
```

Comment: `isset` won't work, since he's using an empty string. Use `empty` instead.